# How to burn ISOs with LXDE + Ubuntu?

Tags: iso, burning

I am trying to burn ISOs with Ubuntu installed with LXDE. In the right click menu, I think Archive Mounter is what I am supposed to use? But when I click that, nothing happens. What can I use to burn ISOs, then?

[image]

Comment: Open with and you select the application you use to burn iso's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install **[brasero](http://packages.ubuntu.com/brasero) [image: Install brasero]** and use that to burn your isos.

Comment: what if it gets stuck at calculating (forgot the word) checksum part. I solved it by going another PC. But will like to fix this

Comment: @jiewmeng what are you talking about, and how is it relevant to the answer?

Comment: I tried burning with brasero, and on one computer, it got stuck at the caculating checksum part

Comment: Disable the checksum plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion you can try for lightweight CD burner from XFCE desktop environment package: xfburn

Answer (score 0):

Might as well chime in with a recommendation of **K3b** for burning ISO's onto optical disks :)

https://userbase.kde.org/K3b

If **xfburn** *(as suggested by Lye Heng Foo)* or **Brasero** *(as suggested by RolandiXor)* don't get good results for you then definitely give it a try.

I suspect xfburn will be the lightest, so might suit your Lubuntu/LXDE setup better.

*KDE applications (like K3b) do tend to have quite a lot of dependencies due to utilising the KDE Frameworks, so if you don't already have a lot of those libraries already installed by other programs then it can look quite daunting at first, but I don't think it's a particularly 'heavy' application in itself.*

It was a long time ago, so Brasero has very likely improved a lot since then, but I had an optical drive that was past it's best and was using cheap 'write once' optical discs and when Brasero failed to complete the job, the disc was useless.

Instead of getting a less terrible optical drive burner, I wasted a bunch of disks and then tried my luck with K3b, with much more successful results.

Entirely anecdotal as evidence, so don't take my shoddy equipment story as anything other than that, but *if you're not getting good results with anything else then it's definitely worth a look*.